# Three.js scene that doesn't work in Chrome using zoom mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, three.js, zooming

I've tested Three.js a simple scene using zooming  TrackballControls.js and it's working perfectly fine just in FireFox

Just one touch to scroll wheel and object just disappear in black screen:

1. Chrome
2. Opera
3. IE-11
4. Microsoft Edge
5. Safari - Absolutely not working !!!:#

[Correct code example, the same behavior in all browsers :](https://jsfiddle.net/rLn2Le2k/1/)

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Basic Scene TrackballControls </title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0; 

        }
        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/TrackballControls.js"></script>

    <script>

        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

        init();
        animate();

        function init(){
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000);<!-- set the far property of  camera to a greater value.-->
            camera.position.z = 500;

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
            controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100, 5, 5, 5, 5);
            //var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true});

            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(cube);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();
        }

        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Trying to change the TrackballControls = function:

```
 . this.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
 . this.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
 . this.panSpeed = 0.3;
```

was completely useless.

So, my question is, what possible cause of this issue?
If someone experienced a similar problem, please share your idea how to fix that.
Thanks!

Comment: I found 0.02 to be a more appropriate zoom speed on Chrome.

Comment: Great! It's appropriate  for the other one as well:
Opera
IE-11
Microsoft Edge  except, Safari (reason unknown) It would be great if creators of TrackballControls.js provide the comment about such important stuff! Thanks a lot!